# How dop I get a temp table column reference in Jooq?

Tags: java, jooq, jooq-codegen

I'm creating a temp table to manipulate some data in MySQL. All the code runs in a `TransactionCallable`.

```
-- Create the temp table
Name tmpTableName = DSL.name(TMP_TABLE_NAME);
dslContext.createTemporaryTable(tmpTableName)        
.as(dslContext.select(TABLE_A.fields()).from(TABLE_A)).withNoData().execute();

Table<Record> tmpTable = DSL.table(tmpTableName);

-- The insert...select here seems to be ok

dslContext.update(tmpTable)
      .set(tmpTable.field("COL_1", String.class), "replacement text")
      .where(tmpTable.field("COL_2", String.class).startsWith("prefix"))
      .execute();
```

The update statement is where there is an error I can't get past. The message is `tmpTable.field("COL_2", String.class) is null`. It seems like the `tmpTable` object isn't actually referencing the temp table.

I thought the problem was in how I'm trying to get the table object with [DSL.table](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/impl/DSL.html#table(java.lang.String)) which sounds like that is for constructing a table from a SQL string.

I tried getting a reference through meta() but the List came back empty.

```
List<Table<?>> tables = dslContext.meta().getTables(tmpTableName);
```

How do I get a reference to the columns/fields of the temp table so I can use them in the update statement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### How to create column references

The identifier based table expression `DSL.table(tmpTableName)` doesn't know anything about its columns, so when you write `tmpTable.field("COL_1")`, that can't dereference any columns. This only works if you're using `Meta` (only if the database reports temp tables, not all do), or generated code.

However, why not just construct standalone field references based on the identifier, like you did with the table:

```java
// You don't really have to qualify your field references in this particular case
Field<String> col1Unqualified = field(name("COL_1"), VARCHAR);

// .. but if you do want to qualify them, here's how:
Field<String> col1Qualified = field(name(TMP_TABLE_NAME, "COL_1"), VARCHAR);
```

The usual static imports are assumed here:

```java
import static org.jooq.impl.DSL.*;
import static org.jooq.impl.SQLDataType.*;
```

### Alternative approaches using generated code

Since your temp table `TMP_TABLE_NAME` has the exact same structure as your `TABLE_A`, you can just call `TABLE_A.rename("TMP_TABLE_NAME")` to get a type safe reference of the temp table with all its columns:

```java
TableA tmp = TABLE_A.rename("TMP_TABLE_NAME");

ctx.update(tmp)
   .set(tmp.COL1, "replacement text")
   .where(tmp.COL2.startsWith("prefix"))
   .execute();
```

Comment: Awesome answer as always. Helpful and I see there’s a blind spot in my understanding.