How to use case_() in JOOQ?
I get an error(java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot interpret argument of type class org.org.impl.CompareCondition as Field: id_ml_model_value = null) when using case_() in jooq, I think it's because I can't use .then(), because in in a similar sql code, everything works correctly:
select distinct kk.id, epk_id, uir, status_code, end_date, sudir_user_name, name_kk
from ccl_test.calculation_kk kk
join ccl_test.values_kk val
on (case resulting_calculation_value
    when 'value_ml_model' then id_ml_model_value=val.id
    when 'value_lm' then id_lm_value=val.id
    when 'value_verifier' then id_verifier_value=val.id
    END)
where status_code='completed'

But when I add the table name tableCalculationKK and tableValuesKK
when("value_ml_model", tableCalculationKK.field("id_ml_model_value",BIGINT).eq(tableValuesKK.field("id",BIGINT)))
it turns out to be a completely different error - java.lang.NullPointerException: null
Method in the repository:
public List<CalculationDTOForAll> getAllCalculation() {
        Table<?> tableCalculationKK = table(name("calculation_kk"));
        Table<?> tableValuesKK = table(name("values_kk"));
        return context.selectDistinct(
                        tableCalculationKK.field("id"),
                        field("epk_id"),
                        field( "uir"),
                        field("status_code"),
                        field("end_date"),
                        field("sudir_user_name"),
                        tableValuesKK.field("name_kk"))
                .from(tableCalculationKK)
                .join(tableValuesKK)
                .on(case_(field("resulting_calculation_value", VARCHAR))
                        .when("value_ml_model",
                                field("id_ml_model_value",BIGINT).eq(tableValuesKK.field("id",BIGINT)))

                        .when("value_lm",
                                field("id_lm_value",BIGINT).eq(tableValuesKK.field("id",BIGINT)))

                        .when("value_verifier",
                                field("id_verifier_value",BIGINT).eq(tableValuesKK.field("id",BIGINT)))

                        .eq(falseCondition()))

                .where(field("status_code").eq("completed"))
                .fetchInto(CalculationDTOForAll.class);
    }

it seems to me that jooq perceives the 2 parameter in .when(,2) as the second condition, and not a condition for combining two tables.
the java class that the records will be mapped to:
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class CalculationDTOForAll {
    private Long        id;
    private Long        epkId;
    private String      uir;
    private String      statusCode;
    @JsonFormat(pattern = "dd.MM.yy")
    private Date        endDate;
    private String      sudirUserName;
    private String      nameKK;
}


It's the same question as this one. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77657567/how-dop-i-get-a-temp-table-column-reference-in-jooq. In short, you want to dereference columns from a table instance that doesn't know its columns: https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/column-expressions/table-columns/dereferenced-table-columns/. But ultimately, why not just use code generation? https://blog.jooq.org/why-you-should-use-jooq-with-code-generation/
